# How to calculate the point where a straight will pass?

Tags: geometry

I have a straight that passes through the points $(a, b)$ and $(c, d)$. If I want to extend this length in an arbitrary value "$V$", how can I calculate the additional points where the straight will pass through?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: $y-b=\frac{d-b}{c-a}(x-a)$

Answer (score 2):

One can easily construct the parametric equations of a line through the points $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$:

$$\begin{align*}x&=(1-t)a+tc\\y&=(1-t)b+td\end{align*}$$

$t=0$ yields the point $(a,b)$, $t=1$ yields $(c,d)$, and values of $t$ outside $[0,1]$ will yield points that weren't in your original line segment...